# Security with OAuth 2.0 json file in my Flutter app source code with published apps

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0

I have made a Flutter app.
At start, i check if the app is launched on mobile device (iOS or Android) or in web browser with "kIsWeb".
Web version is only for administrators.
Source code is the same for mobile and admin.

I want to send notifications to many users at the same time and I work on push notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging API V1.
I seen i can download a json file of service account and store this file in my app for generate an access token when I want to send notifications.

There is not a security problem if i store this json file in a directory of my app and when I publish applications on the stores?

Thanks for your help.